# How do I delay an execution in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i swear i've being looking for the way to solve this many hours before I ask here, I found some codes but still nothing fits to what I need... the thing is that I have some boxes and 1 button for rolling a random style... when I click the button the following code starts;

```
    function roll(){
  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      setInterval(function(){ 
        res = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
        /*document.getElementById("slot-" + res).style.border = "5px solid red";
        document.getElementById("slot-" + res).style.color = "red";*/
        document.getElementById("slot-" + res).className = "col-sm-2 slot-active"; 
      }, 500);
        document.getElementById("slot-" + res).className = "col-sm-2 slot"; 
   } 
};
```

It selects at random between 1 and 10 and changes style class to that box... so... in the line after the loop, i pretend to put original stile back so it gives a look of a random selection... but it doesnt executes, if I put it inside the for loop it executes inmediatly and seems like nothing is happening... im Javascript noob and i'm trying this to learn and practice!... thanks in advance for your help!...

Comment: your actual requirement is not clear

Comment: the last line executes before the code inside the `setInterval` and the code inside will repeatedly execute  every 1/2 second indefinitely. Study some tutorials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use setTimeout(function(){dosomething}, timeout), btw. add console.log('something') to see if the functions are actually executed.

btw. if you're using interval remember you might need to cancel it if you dont want it running forver, you could as well use recurring function (a function calling itself) with some condition on when to do processing or now.

btw2. every time you create interval assign it to some variable or something so you can cancel it!

Comment: Thank you, i added another function with the timeout option you told me... it worked PERFECTLY! now i only have to find a way to stop that lol !

Comment: Hi, just assign it to setTimeout to variable so var something = setTimeout(), later you can do somethjing like that: var myVar;

function myFunction() {
    myVar = setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);
}

function myStopFunction() {
    clearTimeout(myVar);
}

Comment: so basically clearTimeout(variableThatSetTimeoutWasAssignedTo)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a setInterval that will randomly set the selected class, and have a setTimeout to end the execution of said interval, something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/canastro/xxdbjm4n/1/

```
const refreshIntervalId = setInterval(() => {
    $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
  const res = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
  $(`.slot-${res}`).addClass('selected');
}, 500)

setTimeout(() => {
    clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

your answer should be like this.you need to see javascript variable scope.

```js
 function roll(){
 
  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      var res = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
      function active(res){
        setTimeout(function(){ 
        document.getElementById("slot-" + res).className = "col-sm-2 slot-active"; 
      }, 500);
        document.getElementById("slot-" + res).className = "col-sm-2 slot"; 
      }
      active(res);
   } 
};
```

```css
div{
 width:50px;
 height:50px;
 background:#ccc;
 float:left;
 margin:5px;
}
.slot{
 background:#0f0;
}
.slot-active{
 background:#f00;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="roll()" style="display:block;">roll</button>
<div id="slot-1"></div>
<div id="slot-2"></div>
<div id="slot-3"></div>
<div id="slot-4"></div>
<div id="slot-5"></div>
<div id="slot-6"></div>
<div id="slot-7"></div>
<div id="slot-8"></div>
<div id="slot-9"></div>
<div id="slot-10"></div>
```